# Text editor for Windows with TOC, Markdown, syntax coloring, hyperlinks

Tags: windows, text-editor, markdown

I've been using [wikidPad](http://wikidpad.sourceforge.net/) since I remember. My wiki has zillions of words and the database is now very very slow so wikidPad is useless for me. I've come up with the idea to separate some large wikipages into pieces and use another wiki-like software that I could use with wikidPad.

What I need is:

- very lightweight wikidPad alternative with markdowns,
- syntax coloring,
- hyperlinks,
- TOC (ideally with live preview in real time).

Perfect solution would be ReText or Sublime with those features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found something that fits my requirements. It's [**CuteMarkEd**](http://cloose.github.io/CuteMarkEd/).

It has lack of tabs (or back button) so it's not perfect solution for lightweight wiki but TOC, Markdown, code highlighting and live preview works like a charm.